# Error 1010 Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, error-handling

i get Error #1010 when i use this while loop:

```
while (pos.length>0)
{
    coo = pos.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * pos.length),1)[0];

    (pos_array[index]).x = coo.x;
    (pos_array[index]).y = coo.y;
    index++;
}
```

The error says: `A term is undefined and has no properties.`

What is wrong with my loop because I used the same loop for other programms and i got no such error.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Can't tell from this code. 'pos', 'pos_array', any element in 'pos_array', any element in 'pos' and 'index' could all be undefined.

Comment: they are all defined:
     var coo:Object:
var pos_array:Array= new Array();
var index:uint=0;

Comment: What about the elements in 'pos' and 'pos_array'? On what line is the error thrown? You don't have a debugger at your disposal?

Comment: everything is fine. I used the debugger to see which line it is.
and the error is in the loop. but don't know where

Comment: Does the element in 'pos_array' already exist when you set its 'x' property? e.g. when you do '(pos_array[0]).x = coo.x', is there an instance of a class with attribute x at that position in the array?

Comment: i don't konw what to change in the code because i used the same code in a as3 file and everything was ok. but this time i am using a package an classes. don' know why is not working now

Comment: package v. FLA is not the issue. its gotta be here: `pos_array[index]`. it looks like `pos_array` does not contain any any/enough values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop is breaking.

pos.length will never change and eventually `pos_array[index]` will be out of bounds.

When when you are out of bounds it is undefined.
So basically you are doing.

```
undefined.x = coo.x;
```

And just like the error says undefined has has no properties.

I can't see how this loop ever worked.

Try this instead much cleaner

```
var savedX:Number = 0
for each( var obj:Object in pos_array ){
  coo = new MovieClip()
  coo = pos.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * pos.length),1)[0];
  obj.x = savedX;
  obj.y = 0;
  savedX += coo.width;
}
```

Comment: i tryed that and I got no error but the mc's are not arranged side by side like they used to be. they are now stacked.
how can i arrange them side? i have allready stored positions in array pos

Comment: your logic is flawed. you are using an array to store positions which is fine however, you accessing them randomly which has the possibility of using one position more then once. you need to remove the element from the pos array once you have "used" that position.

Comment: i would do it like this:
    for each( var obj:Object in pos_array ){
  coo = pos.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * pos.length),1)[0];
  obj.x+=loader.width/4;
  obj.y =0;
if(x>loader.width)
{
x=0;
y=loader.height/2;
}
}

Comment: I'm not sure that code will do what you are expecting it to do. I would start with verifying the values of pos and make sure they are all good locations.

Comment: ok can you tell me a way to do this. I have stored some mc's in an array and i want to put these mc's on the stage side by side.
how can I do that?
thank you

Comment: Edited my answer for you. Please keep to the format of the forum of ask a question and get an answer. When you get a correct answer accept it and post a new question if you have more questions.

Comment: this worked to arrange them side by side but the mc's are not mixed up with each other. 
i thank you that you took your time to help me

Comment: Was in the shower this morning and your issue with the side by side thing popped into my head. Anyway I updated my answer for you to fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the collection contains, I'm assuming it is filled with DisplayObjects or an object that has x and y properties?

Cast the reference so the compiler understands what the collection contains.  For example:

```
DisplayObject(pos_array[index]).x = coo.x;
DisplayObject(pos_array[index]).y = coo.y;
```

...or whatever type your collection contains.

Comment: if i change the loop condition to : "while(pos.length==0)" it works

Comment: yes the array contains movie clips but this is not the solution because i get a new error " undefined method"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **pos.length** and **pos_array.length** are not equal when the loop starts.

Try this:

```
while (pos.length>0)
{

    coo = pos.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * pos.length),1)[0];
    if (pos_array[index])
    {
        (pos_array[index]).x = coo.x;
        (pos_array[index]).y = coo.y;
    }
    index++;

}
```